# (Get-WmiObject) How to change the "Lockout" property?

Tags: powershell

In the Get-WmiObject, how can I change the "Lockout" property to "False" for all users who have "Lockout" set to "True" ?

Here is my code for now :

```
$users = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName ***** -Class Win32_UserAccount -Filter "LocalAccount='True' and Lockout='True' and Name like '****%'"
foreach ($user in $users){???}
```

I don't know what to write inside the curly brackets.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass the the unlock to each user

```
$users = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName ***** -Class Win32_UserAccount -Filter "LocalAccount='True' and Lockout='True' and Name like '****%'"
    foreach ($user in $users){
        Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_UserAccount -ComputerName **** -Filter "Name=$user" |% {$_.Lockout = $false;$_.put()}
            }
```

You should be looking into using CimInstance instead of WMIObject

Comment: Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

```
$users = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName ***** -Class Win32_UserAccount -Filter "LocalAccount='True' and Lockout='True' and Name like '****%'"
foreach ($user in $users){
   $user.Lockout = $false
   $user.Put()
}
```

EDIT :

The solution is to call the "Lockout" parameter with the variable "$user"
:
$user.Lockout
Then, we must apply the boolean value "False" like this :
$user.Lockout = $false
Finaly, we must save our changes by calling this method :
$user.Put()

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.